# Java: reliably calling GC?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

In some library found on google code I came across this util method:

```
public static void gc(){
    Object obj = new Object();
    WeakReference ref = new WeakReference<Object>(obj);
    obj = null;
    while(ref.get()!=null)
    System.gc();
}
```

Its doc says it provides a reliable way to call GC, because calling System#gc() is just a hint without any guarantees. I showed it my senior, and he said I should think about why this method is invalid.
I read some articles on weak references but I'm still confused.
Can somebody show me the point?

Comment: focus on your business logic..let java handle the rest! :)

Comment: I absolutely agree :) I would never rely on anything like "calling GC". I'm just curious.

Comment: If gc() is just a hint, there's no reason to assume that GC will ever actually happen. What are you not doing here that really makes gc happen (think about what GC is for...)? If never actually happens, what will your method do?

Comment: try running that with [`-XX:+DisableExplicitGC`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)

Comment: Garbage collection, like compiler optimisation is a huge ranging area. It is a common research theme for post grads and others. It's way beyond my understanding to be blunt, and there are many implementations of it. There is no really robust and 'reliable' way to call it, and as the others said you kind of have to leave it in Java's hands! It seems to me like you have to flirt with GC and hope it gives you some sugar!

Comment: If it is a hint the first time, it is also a hint the second time and third, .... so putting it in a loop won't change the fact it is a hint.

Comment: I'm surprised that method doesn't infinite-loop every time. When you call ref.get() you're pulling the referent into a local variable or stack slot, so it could keep the object alive during garbage collection. At worst it's an infinite loop and at best it's a very ugly hack. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey If my teacher makes the same hint everyday about a question on the final exam, I'm eventually going to take the hint :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have direct experience with the supposed "safe GC" idiom you have posted.

It doesn't work.

The reason is quite simple: just the fact that a weak ref is cleared is *not* a signal that the object has been collected; it only means that it has become unreachable through any strong or soft reference. In my experience this signal arrives before the object is reclaimed.

A better attempt would be to use a Phantom reference, which at least ensures that the object has entered the *finalizable* state, but once again, it can still be occupying the heap, and in practice it still *is* occupying it. Another explanation could be that this particular object, obviously residing in Eden space, did get reclaimed, but the GC run which did it was not exhaustive and there is more memory to reclaim in other generations.

On the other hand, I have very reliably used this trivial idiom:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { System.gc(); Thread.sleep(500); }
```

Try it and see if it works for you. The `sleep` part is optional: it is needed only if `System.gc()` uses concurrent sweeping.

If you object to the apparent fickleness of this approach, just remember that *any* approach to explicit GC-ing is fickle. This one is at least honest about it—and just happens to work on actual systems. It is, naturally, non-portable and can cease to work at any time for a large array of reasons. Even so, it is the best you'll ever get.

Comment: Agreed, I would like to know what the impact in "object strength" is for the Object being declared in the same method as the code to GC. Just seems like a bad plan, trying to garbage collect an object which you just declared 4 lines up. Might be better to loose all references to it as soon as possible rather.

Comment: @grep In OP's code the reference to `obj` is indeed explicitly cleared.

Comment: Weak refs are only cleared by the GC which means that yes as soon as it becomes null the GC has indeed run. The problem is that the problem you were trying to solve "Has the object been collected"? is not the same as "Has the GC been run at least once?". Finalizers and all that..

Comment: @Voo Another problem is that this object is 100% sure to be in the eden space and will be reclaimed by a minor collection. The practical fact is that `System.gc` triggers a major collection, but that's yet another bet you can lose.

Answer (score 2):

The point is, that `System.gc()` does not need to clean up all weak references. And consider some Java virtual machines too. If `System.gc` for once (the first time) does decide to *not* clean that reference, it is very likely to the next call. Hence you have a **possibly infinite loop**. Probably depending on other threads changing the state for the garbage collection to terminate the loop.

So: once is enough.

Comment: In my experience a second call almost always reclaims some more memory. Could be the finalization cycle.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik the same experience too (Oracle jvm). Though if gc is implemented as _"if current state has ample room return"_ then an unbounded loop is silly. And even Oracle's gc has many options. So twice doing a gc should be sufficient. In fact creating an object to trigger garbage collection is perverse.

Comment: Exactly, I typically use two calls and sometimes add a third just for good measure. I sometimes print `totalMemory - freeMemory` to confirm that the third one did not release any more memory.

Answer (score 1):

There is *no* way to guarantee a GC call because just as the documentation says `System.gc` is just a hint that can be ignored by the system.

So assume that the JVM ignores `System.gc` - in that case the whole thing just loops until some other part of the systems causes a GC. If you run single-threaded or nobody else allocates much memory you basically create an inifite loop here.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that your thread will stop and wait until the weak reference is cleared, thus "simulating" garbage collection. There's no guarantee when (or indeed even IF) this will actually happen.

You could be stuck waiting on this `while` for a long, long time.

Comment: It blocks and you either wait forever or manually kill it. I thought that's what I just said?

Answer (score 0):

> Programmatic we need to ensure that, when a obj is removed then its corresponding entry should be removed. Only then, that object becomes a candidate for garbage collection. Otherwise, even though it is not used at run-time, this stale object will not be garbage collected.

The object to which this reference refers, or null if this reference object has been cleared.
As your object reference of WeakReference class. so it will not give null. but after removing gc., it provide null.

```
 Object obj = new Object();
         WeakReference ref = new WeakReference<Object>(obj);
         obj = null;
         if(ref.get()!=null)
         {
             System.gc();
             System.out.println("remove ref");
         }
         if(ref.get()!=null){
             System.out.println("not execute"); 
         }
```

**Output:**

```
remove ref
```

Don't assign null value to obj.

```
 Object obj = new Object();
         WeakReference ref = new WeakReference<Object>(obj);
         if(ref.get()!=null)
         {
             System.gc();
             System.out.println("remove ref");
         }
         if(ref.get()!=null){
             System.out.println("execute"); 
         }
```

**Output:**

```
remove ref
execute
```

Answer (score 0):

Code that tries to force GC is usually a sign for an underlying bigger problem (i.e. design issue or missing knowledge on the developers part).

I have seen a few use cases where calling `System.gc()` in production code actually makes sense, for example, before printing the current memory usage - it doesn't matter if the values are off but we'd like to improve chances the values are as small as possible. Of course, we knew that GC was enabled - we used this to automatically detect memory leaks on a QA system.

In general, calling `System.gc()` yells "my code is buggy and I don't know how to fix it!".